# List of pages from wikipedia

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia

I build an application which gives you to select subjects you like, those subjects should be in DB.

There is millions 'likes'! (pizza, PHP, manchester united, any movie.. i dont know), so I decided to insert those 'likes' to my DB with Wikipedia.

Well, there is a way to get all of those 'likes' (with the api I have a limit [500 per search I think)? or another solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I just want to get list of pages from wikipedia. in my website the user can select somthings he likes. (from the list)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there will be dozens fans of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23155_Judithblack or of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Secretary_of_State_election,_2006

Comment: Why not do it the usual way, i.e. let users manually enter new likes, if they can't find something on the list of existing ones?

Comment: Mchl - It importants to my application. I dont want that any user enters 'pizza' and the other 'piza' or somthing like that.

Comment: I would suggest a spell check instead. If there are many possible spellings, sort them by popularity (i.e. how many others have liked each). I guess you could use the Wikipedia page titles to "seed" the system instead of using a normal dictionary. I also suggest that you read up on Folksonomy. From Wikipedia: "An empirical analysis of the complex dynamics of tagging systems, published in 2007,[5] has shown that consensus around stable distributions and shared vocabularies does emerge, even in the absence of a central controlled vocabulary."

Comment: @Luis Do you want to download the content of every page on Wikipedia, or do you just want to obtain a list of all page titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the WikiMedia technical documentation.  There is a section that talks about [query continuation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries).

Alternatively, you could download a Wikipedia dump, install your own copy of WikiMedia and query to your hearts content.  The dumps are huge, but depending on how much stuff you want to extract, this may finish the task faster, and with less impact on the Wikipedia service.

Comment: Is there any way to simply obtain the list of page titles, without downloading the entire XML dump?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what information you are actually trying to retrieve from Wikipedia. Page titles?

Wikimedia provides XML files containing all page titles for all their projects at [download.wikimedia.org](http://download.wikimedia.org). (Sadly the dumps seem to be currently unavailable due to hardware problems). You could parse the XML file and store all the titles in your own database.

Answer (score 0):

Dumps are available from wikipedia in various formats, with varying levels of detail.

Pick one that best suits your needs and parse it.

Comment: You mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download ? links dont work.

Comment: @Paul: I'am interested by such dump 'with various levels of details'. Can you provide a link ?